# How do you make a div clip its visible content?

Tags: html, css

For instance like in the image below. You have the content spanning the entire page but you want the div "window" to only show part of it? I tried making two divs, one an inner and one an outer.

The inner had it's position fixed (so based on the browser) and spanning the entire page while the outer was absolute and positioned where the red rectangle is. I then placed the inner (with the page content) in the outer div but didn't work at all

I also tried messing with negative padding but that isn't allowed

[cropped div example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqJ0M.png)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `overflow`, `overflow-y`, or `overflow-x` style with a specific `width` or `height`.

If you want to simply hide large content, use `overflow:hidden`. If you want to also show the scroll bar, use `overflow:scroll`.

Use `overflow-x` to hide content whose width exceeds the container width. Use `overflow-y` to hide content whose height exceeds the container height. Use `overflow` to hide content whose width & height exceeds the container width & height.

```
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <DIV STYLE="width:20ex; overflow-x:scroll; border:1px solid black;">
      <NOBR>very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text</NOBR>
    </DIV>
    <BR />
    <DIV STYLE="height:3em; overflow-y:scroll; border:1px solid black;">
      line 1<BR />
      line 2<BR />
      line 3<BR />
      line 4<BR />
      line 5<BR />
      line 6
    </DIV>
    <BR />
    <DIV STYLE="width:20ex; height:3em; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid black;">
      <NOBR>very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text</NOBR>
      line 1<BR />
      line 2<BR />
      line 3<BR />
      line 4<BR />
      line 5<BR />
      line 6
    </DIV>
    <BR />
    <DIV STYLE="width:20ex; height:3em; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid black;">
      <NOBR>very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text</NOBR>
      line 1<BR />
      line 2<BR />
      line 3<BR />
      line 4<BR />
      line 5<BR />
      line 6
    </DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.panel {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

`overflow:auto` will show a scroll bar when it is necessary, but not unless its necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried creating a transparent div to float over the page content?

Since you can't specify a margin or padding colour, you'd need to have 5 divs: top, left centre, right, bottom.  These would span 100%, and the centre would be the transparent one.  The others would be a solid background colour, or semi-transparent as in your example.  Having a transparent centre div would probably mean you can't click on content beneath it.  You might want to have no centre div instead.